Father/daughter 90s thriller with eyes in 2 different colors
I have confused the movie 'Along Came A Spider' with a different movie. The movie I am looking for is about a detective or writer who takes his daughter to this house. She is about 6 to 8 years old. She draws and talks about this little girl who has two different-colored eyes and eventually her brown eyes become one blue and one brown. The father dies at the end and they believe the girl is cured but in the last cutscene of the movie you see her finish a picture and the girl in the picture has two-colored eyes. She turns her eyes and you see her having two eye colors. It has been bothering me that I can't find it. I believe it is a 90s to latest 2003 movie. I watched it nearly 10 years ago or so.

It sounds like maybe you're confusing two movies?

The Unborn from 2009, which is about a girl with brown and blue eyes who's haunted by a vengeful ancestor, 
Hide and Seek from 2005, which stars Robert DeNiro as a psychologist and Dakota Fanning as his daughter who draws pictures of her "friend" Charlie who is a murderer. At the end of the movie, she draws herself having two heads.

